# How can I ask to be part of the interview process?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

My team is in the process of hiring a new developer. Although roles can change, at present we plan for this new developer to take over the project I've been working on for the past year and a half as their primary responsibility. Nobody else on the team has knowledge of the old project like I do, so I would be working most closely with this new hire.

However, my involvement to the hiring process has been limited to giving feedback on resumes - a different team member has been conducting all the interviews. At this rate I won't even meet the hire until they start! Admittedly that team member is more senior and has interviewed people people before (and is a decent judge of character), but a different coworker remarked how it was a little weird that I wasn't more involved, given that I'd be the one interacting most with this new person.

My goal is not to take over interviews as I have no experience with that, although I do have a couple project specific questions I could ask. Ideally I would prefer to just observe.

I am also concerned that management might be thinking of wasting resources (e.g. "why pay two people to sit in interviews instead of working when just one can do it") so this makes me unsure about how to approach them.

Is it appropriate for me to request more involvement in the hiring process? If so, how do I approach it?

Comment: Once the new employee takes over your role what happens to you? If you are leaving they may want to avoid having you play a major role in the hiring process.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep I will be taking the lead on a new project. I'll still be working here on the same team and am expected to be "backup" on the old project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> is it appropriate for me to request more involvement in the hiring
>   process? If so, how do I approach it?

It's appropriate to ask if you can be involved. But you don't want it to appear as if you wish to continue to be in control of this project.

I'd suggest something like "Hey boss. Would you like me to be part of the interview team, rather than just looking over resumes? I think I can add value by asking xxx..."

Be sensitive to the reply. If you are told "No thanks. I think [experienced senior team member] can handle it." then just let it go and focus on your new role.

Comment: But, if you are not to participate, since you say I do have a couple project specific questions I could ask", you might want to discuss them with the person who *will* be conducting the interview